# Como manipular um JSON com fasterXML em java?

Tags: java, json, simplexml

Tenho um json que vem do banco MongoDB, tenho que pegar e manipular o json 
usando fasterXml. Terei que pegar os nomes das propriedades do json e separa-las com ponto(.) em vez de virgula(,)

Tipo assim :

```
"type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : {
      "type" : "any"
    },
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "version" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "code" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "clazz" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

E mostrar assim :

```
properties{id.name.version.code.clazz};
```

Mostrar tudo o que tem dentro da pai que é "properties", ou algo parecido!!

Comment: Você precisa saber todas as propriedades filhas de `properties`, é isso? O que tentou até agora? Dê mais detalhes sobre a sua necessidade/problema.

Comment: consegui fazer colocarei a solução aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No meu estou usando log para mostrar em vez do sysout

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<String> node = new ArrayList<>();          
JsonNode objectRoot = mapper.readTree(code);
Iterator<String> fields = objectRoot.fieldNames();
String field = "";
while(fields.hasNext()) {
    field = fields.next();

    node.add(field);
}
LOGGER.info("GRAU I: "+ field);

JsonNode arrayRoot = mapper.readTree(code);

Iterator<JsonNode> elements = arrayRoot.elements();

JsonNode element;

while(elements.hasNext()) {
    element = elements.next(); 
    field = "";
    fields = element.fieldNames();

    while(fields.hasNext()){
        field = fields.next();

        node.add(field);

        LOGGER.info("GRAU II em diante: "+ field);
    }

    return node;

}
```

Acho que é isso

Comment: modo mais simples

Comment: bruno césar ???